# subs(sinc(K), K, 0) where K is symbol will return NaN. Shouldn't it be 1?

Tags: matlab, symbolic-computation

MATLAB `sinc(0)` will return 1 as it should. But `sinc(K)` of some symbol `K` for which a value of zero is substituted will return `NaN.`

The following code illustrates the above:

```
sinc(0)  % calculate sinc of 0, this will return 1

K = sym('K'); % define symbol K

% try to substitute value 0 for K in sinc(K), this will return NaN
subs(sinc(K), K, 0)
```

Can I force `sinc` to return 1 in the symbolic case (without knowing the value of `K` in advance)?

```
MATLAB Version: 8.0.0.783 (R2012b)
Symbolic Math Toolbox  Version 5.9  (R2012b)
```

Comment: The problem seems to be the `find` in the `sinc` function: `find(sym('K'))` returns the an empty array. (Same MATLAB and Sym Math Toolbox version)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are diving `0/0`, i.e. `NaN` by direct substitution in `sin(pi*K)/(K*pi)`.

This is what `sinc` is actually doing to circumvent that.

```
i = find(x==0);                                                              
x(i) = 1;                                
y = sin(pi*x)./(pi*x);                                                     
y(i) = 1;
```

You can get the same effect by adding a small regularizer to your values:

```
subs(sinc(K), K, 0+eps) 
ans =

     1
```