# matlab not allowed sinc(0)

Tags: matlab, plot, symbolic-math

I try to plot these 2 graphs on the same plot but matlab return error 'can't divide by zero' and refer me to sinc of 0.
I don't know what to do bc `sinc(0)=1`, I don't understand the problem.

**my code:**

```
syms x  
ezplot(heaviside(x+1) - heaviside(x-1), [-2, 2])  
hold  
t=-2:0.1:2;  
syms k  
r=symsum( ((sinc(k/2)/2)*exp((1i)*k*pi*(t/2))), -1,1);  
plot(t,r)
```

**problem:**

```
  ??? Error: File: aa.m Line: 6 Column: 18
Unexpected MATLAB expression.

Current plot held
??? Error using ==> mupadmex
Error in MuPAD command: Division by zero [_power];

during evaluation of 'sum::sum'

Error in ==> sym.symsum at 74
   r = mupadmex('symobj::map',f.s,'symobj::symsum',x.s,a.s,b.s);

Error in ==> aa at 6
r=symsum( ((sinc(k/2)/2)*exp((1i)*k*pi*(t/2))), -1,1);
```

Comment: Write `type sinc` and tells us what appears. Matlab Signal Processing Toolbox gives `1` for input `0`, as it should

Comment: sinc(0) returm 1 in matlab

Comment: So `sinc(0)` is not the problem. You need to rewrite your answer and be more specific about the error

Comment: @LuisMendo I posted the problem, any idea?

Comment: The problem is that Matlab's symbolic `sinc` function gives `NaN`,  instead of `1`, for input 0. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15815613/subssinck-k-0-where-k-is-symbol-will-return-nan-shouldnt-it-be-1)

Comment: tnx but Im not sure where to write 'subs(sinc(K), K, 0+eps)'

Comment: If you take a look into the sinc.m, the error becomes obvious. For input arguments of type sym , the special rule 'i=find(x==0);' never hits. This results in an `nan` for zero, instead of a 1.

Comment: @Daniel how do I find sinc.m file?

Comment: type in `edit sinc.m`

Comment: @Daniel, OK and where do I write 'subs(sinc(K), K, 0+eps)'? in the sinc.m?

Comment: @user3439500: I don't know how `subs` could solve the issue.

Comment: @LuisMendo: There is no symbolic `sinc`, i.e., `sym/sinc`. Non-overloaded functions aren't guaranteed to work (especially in this case as it's part of a toolbox) MuPAD also doesn't appear to have a version of the function either. Seems like something that that one could submit as a feature request...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Another solution, instead of using an alternative definition with the gamma function, I added a correction to redefine the x=0 point.

The original function has a 0/0 situation, I redefined it using a correction function with correction(0)=1 and correction(1)=0 otherwise. This changes to function to 1/1 at sinc(0).

```
%correction(0)=1, correction(x)=0 otherwise. A little bit idiotic, but I'm unable to define this in a simpler way which is compartible to the symbolic toolbox:
correction=@(x)(((heaviside(x)-.5).^2)-.25)*-4
%redefine sinc using the original function, but use correction(x) to fix sinc(0)
ssinc=@(x)((sin(pi*x)+correction(x))./((pi*x)+correction(x)))

syms x  
ezplot(heaviside(x+1) - heaviside(x-1), [-2, 2])  
hold  
t=-2:0.1:2;  
syms k  
r=symsum( ((ssinc(k/2)/2)*exp((1i)*k*pi*(t/2))), -1,1);  
plot(t,r)
```

Answer (score 2):

Use this alternative definition for sinc:

```
ssinc=@(X)(1./(gamma(1+X).*gamma(1-X)))

syms x  
ezplot(heaviside(x+1) - heaviside(x-1), [-2, 2])  
hold  
t=-2:0.1:2;  
syms k  
r=symsum( ((ssinc(k/2)/2)*exp((1i)*k*pi*(t/2))), -1,1);  
plot(t,r)
```

This code uses an alternative definition of the sinc function:
[image]

(Source: [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sinc_function))

Comment: +1 Hey, very clever! Where did you get that definition of `sinc` from?

Comment: I found it on the german wikipedia page for the sinc function, but for some reason I can't reach wikipedia at the moment. Probably you can find the definition on the english page as well.

Comment: @Daniel - I tried to chage the domain from (-1,1) to (-7,7) or other domain that include 0 and it doesn't work. only on (-1,1).
am I missing something here?

Comment: I found another solution, hopefully this will fix all issues.